# Remove many many many files from a folder

Tags: bash, shell, rm, options

I have a folder with 137795 files in it.  I need to delete all of them.  When I run `rm *` I get `-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long`.  How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I can see you don't need to remove your dir , only files inside. So you can recreate it

```
rm -r /path/to/dir && mkdir /path/to/dir
```

or even delete only files inside

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -delete
```

afair first one works faster.

UPD. Note that way with `find` might be not optimal from space consumption point of view, as directory size will be reduced only after `fsck`. [Details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167025/how-to-update-directory-size-after-file-removal).

Comment: Thanks - I knew there was going to be some elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround #1:

```
find /path/to/dir -delete
```

Workaround #2:

```
rm a*;

rm b*;

rm c*;

etc
```

Comment: you don't need to add `-name "*"` to find all files. It finds so by default.

Comment: using `-name "*"` seems a bit redundant, could you explain why you chose that instead of just a `find /path/to/dir -delete`, other than just using the same glob as the OP?

Comment: Also, depending on the implementation or age of your `find`, "*" might not include files that start with a "." (current versions of findutils does include that dotted files).

Answer (score -2):

Using `find` is probably the best bet.  Some of the problems with the other answers are either not deleting everything inside the directory or deleting the directory itself.  You can either use `ls` with `xargs`, if there are no special characters, or `find` with certain options.

```
ls -1 | xargs rm -r
```

or

```
find . -depth -path ./.* -prune -o -not -name . -delete
```

This will ignore anything in the current directory starting with `.` (`-prune`) and will remove any other file or directory, as long as it is not the top directory (`.`).  The `-depth` will look inside directories first, which will avoid a 'directory not empty' error.  If the `-not` argument is not available on your system, then use `!`.

Comment: Do *not* parse `ls`, or expect things to break. Badly. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I had mentioned that above: "if there are no special characters".